# angular 5 setting child component property from parent component

Tags: angular

I want to set the child component property from parent component

parent.component.html

```
<div>
<child-detail #myCarousel [childList]="detail.List" ></child-detail>
</div>
```

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: "parent",
  templateUrl: "./parent.component.html",
 })  
export class AppComponent { 
  public detail; // it is of JSON type
}
```

child.component.ts

```
@component({
 selector:'child-detail',
 templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildDetailComponent{
  @Input() public childList;   // that list of array type
}
```

child.component.html

```
<div *ngFor = "let list of childList">
 <li>{{list}} </li>
</div>
```

I know i can set this property by `@Input()` binding , but this will set only at the time of initializing of the component , I want to set it programmaticaly in intermediate at some point .

I know I can access this child property in parent using

```
@ViewChild(ChildDetailComponent) childDetailComponent: ChildDetailComponent;
console.log(this.childDetailComponent.childList);
```

But I want to set it programatically at any event of parent.

Comment: So why can't you use `input` properties and populate that input property on an event on parent?

Comment: *but this will set only at the time of initializing of the component *?? This is not true. It will be set whenever you change the prop in parent. Read about `ngOnChanges()` hook

Comment: @xyz can you please elaborate this.

Comment: when ever the value of `childList` change in the parent component the value of the childList in the childComponent will also be updated but if you went to change the value of `childList` in the parent component when the value of `childList` change in the child component you can use set method for the `childList` `Input`

Comment: Just a note. You're using TypeScript. TypeScript has types. So why, instead of using `// that list of array type`, don't you properly declare the type of the variable?

Comment: It's component interaction documents Angular here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @xyz  But ngOnChanges() detect only primary type change so this life cycle hook will run , but in case of object property changes it will not run .

Comment: @SunnyGoel: Is the change detection strategy of your child `onPush`? Also If the prop is changed in your parent then you want to reflect in child immediately or after some time when an specific event occurs?

Comment: @SunnyGoel Check the `@Component` decorator of the child, do you see any key for *changeDetection?*

Comment: @xyz i have not define any  `changeDetectionStratergy` in `@component` annotation.

Comment: @SunnyGoel Please use *@* and mention the username that way the user will be notifed when you comment anything. So you didn't answer my other question, do you want to reflect the change immediately or after some event?

Comment: @xyz yes i want to reflect the change immediately .

Answer (score 1):

You can use service for the sharing data pragmatically.

**Step 1**: Create data share service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

**Step 2:** Change message

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }
```

**Step 3:** Get message

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

Comment: You should add DataService at  `providers: [DataService]` in app.module.ts otherwise following error `NullInjectorError: No provider for DataService!` will come.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're doing it without using the `@Input` property.

Whenever the input you've passed to it changes, it will also reflect in the Child Component. You can track it in `ngOnChanges` in the Child Component. Just try `log`ging to the `console`

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  detail: any = {
    childList: []
  };

  setChildList() {
    this.detail.childList = [
      { id: 1, name: 'John' },
      ...
    ];
  }

}
```

And in the template:

```
<button (click)="setChildList()">Set Child List</button>
<hello [childList]="detail.childList"></hello>
```

Here the `@Input` property is changing on the Click of the Button. But in your case, you can simply call the `setChildList` method your event.

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdfvgf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: But ngOnChanges() detect only primary type change so this life cycle hook will run , but in case of object property changes it will not run .

Comment: Judging from what you're saying, looks like you have a `ChangeDetectionStrategy` of `OnPush` on your Component. In that case it will run only if there's a change in the reference of the `@Input` Object.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make any sense in that case. I'm passing the input to the child component just like you want to. And if you have a look at my StackBlitz Sample, it's passing the value as expected and updating it in the Child Component.

Comment: you can check the following URL https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-onchanges-simplechanges-example  . ( in case of object property change this technique will not work)

Comment: Did you even check the Sample StackBlitz? Passing Objects as `@Input` is exactly what I'm doing there. And it's detecting the changes and updating the Child Component as well as the view.

Answer (score 0):

use `@input` in child component. can listen to the changes in child component using `ngOnChanges`.

```
@Input() name: string;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  const name: SimpleChange = changes.name;
  console.log('prev value: ', name.previousValue);
  console.log('got name: ', name.currentValue);
}
```

working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvimuw)